# QSpatialite broken after update to QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, python, osx, qspatialite

Lately I updated from QGIS 2.14 (LTS) to 2.18 on Mac OS X. Since then, the QSpatiaLite plugin has ceased to work, yielding following error message:
[image: Error message after clicking on the QSpatiaLite button]

I have tried the following to repair the problem, without success:

1. Removing the SpatiaLite DB from the DB Manager Plugin and re-adding it. I am then normally prompted by SpatiaLite to create a new DB, however SpatiaLite can't connect to it, I get the following two errors:

[image: First error message][image: Second error message]

1. Reinstalling QGIS 2.14 with all package dependencies from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis
2. Installing QGIS from brew as

   brew install osgeo/osgeo4mac/qgis-lts
3. Removing all QGIS files with terminal, like:

   sudo rm -R /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/
   sudo rm -R /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/
   sudo rm -R /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/
   sudo rm -R /Users/[myusername]/.qgis2
   sudo rm -R /Applications/QGIS.app/

Answer (score 1):

QSpatialite uses Pyspatialite and there is a path problem in the Kyng Chaos SQLite installer, look at [Mac QGIS 2.14: error loading module “processing”. No module named pyspatialite [duplicate]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220745/mac-qgis-2-14-error-loading-module-processing-no-module-named-pyspatialite#comment339711_220745) and [Pyspatialite installation error on MacOSX (QGIS plugin)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/216874/2581)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I've verified it and the paths are consistent