# QGIS Spatialite error: No Such Function: spatialite_version

Tags: qgis, spatialite, midvatten

I am trying to use **Midvatten** on **QGIS 2.18.13** on a **mac**.  When I create a new database, I get

> "no such function: spatialite_version" (see error message below).

I've uninstalled and reinstalled **QGIS** (using Kyngchaos's packages) and **Midvatten**. None of that has helped.

How do I get this basic spatialite function working?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/Becca/.qgis2/python/plugins/midvatten/midvatten.py",
>   line 853, in new_db
>       newdbinstance = newdb(verno)
>
> File
>   "/Users/Becca/.qgis2/python/plugins/midvatten/tools/create_db.py",
>   line 41, in **init**
>       self.create_new_db(verno,user_select_CRS,EPSG_code, delete_srids)  #CreateNewDB(verno)
>
> File
>   "/Users/Becca/.qgis2/python/plugins/midvatten/tools/create_db.py",
>   line 82, in create_new_db
>       versionstext = self.cur.execute('select spatialite_version()').fetchall()
>
> OperationalError: no such function: spatialite_version

Comment: would contact the plugin maintainer https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/blob/master/midvatten.py

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the [KyngChaos SQLite Framework](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) ?

It contains Spatialite and pyspatialite

In Python

```
import pyspatialite
# location of the pyspatialite module
pyspatialite.__file__
'/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/__init__.pyc'
```

The error comes from the line 82 of your [create_db.py](https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/blob/master/tools/create_db.py) file (`versionstext = self.cur.execute('select spatialite_version()').fetchall(): OperationalError: no such function: spatialite_version`) and with a correct installation, it works without problem.

```
from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as sqlite  # line 30 
conn = sqlite.connect("Midv.sqlite")
cur = conn.cursor()
print cur.execute('select spatialite_version()').fetchall() #line 82
[(u'4.3.0a',)]
```

Comment: I am using the Kyngchaos Sqlite Framework.  The pyspatialite file is in the right place but still I get the no such function: spatialite_version error.  I tried to just set the version in create_db.py but then got a series of errors about not being able to create some (but not all) of the standard tables.

Comment: Look at [Pyspatialite installation error on MacOSX (QGIS plugin)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/216874)